# magento throws "Request Timeout" error when creating shipments

Tags: shipment

When I am trying to create shipment for an order, the page throws this error:

> Request Timeout

This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'."

When I Investigate the problem by exploring the code by creating log, Its stops on random code lines. I am stuck now, what to do, how to know what is the error and which operation is creating the problem. This problem only appears for amazon orders.

Answer (score 1):

Timeout means, something needs to long :-)

1. Is there an API call against amazon?
2. Do you have any actions which fire only for amazon orders?

Check the HTTP response, is there any? This error messages looks like generated by the browser, so the question is, what happend on HTTP level.